# How to pass additional parameter with object in Web API,with ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net web api.I am using MVC with that. I am trying to call below ajax call but it alway give me 404 error.

It I try without three parameters "Hash", "AccessKey","Path" - then it allows me to call method of http://www.xxx.xys/rest/createnew and gives response good as I wish.

but when I add these three("Hash", "AccessKey","Path" ) parameters it always gives me error not found(404) error.

here no error due to cross domain as becuase it is running good wihtout three parameters.
I want to pass three parameters as argument not as properties of object CreateParameter.not in header requset. only I want to pass them in parameters.

```
 function CreateTicket() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.xxx.xys/rest/createnew',

            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                MerchantID: $("#txtMerchantID").val(), TicketCategoryID: $("#txtTicketCategoryID").val(), GroupID: $("#txtGroupID").val(), TicketSubCategoryID: $("#txtSubCategoryID").val(), TicketPriorityID: $("#txtTicketPriorityID").val(), Summary: '' + $("#txtSubject").val() + '',
Hash: "EI2nkSoqRN5cBO/ctXF90tl+c0UTW/euI8NZwsG8ZBE=", AccessKey: "d357cf6e-bb14-452e-8044-68c699503c2b", Path: "api/TicketAPIs/GetTicketsByFilter"
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.IsSuccess) {

                    alert('created');
                }
                else {
                    alert('error');
                }

            },
            error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

and

```
 [HttpPost]
    public CreateTicketResult createnew([FromBody]CreateParameter ObjParameter,string Hash, string AccessKey, string Path)
    {
        //code here
}
and I have also tried with below but not working.

[HttpPost]
    public CreateTicketResult createnew(CreateParameter ObjParameter,string Hash, string AccessKey, string Path)
    {
        //code here
}


 public class CreateParameter
    {

        public int MerchantID { get; set; }
        public short TicketCategoryID { get; set; }
        public short GroupID { get; set; }
        public short TicketSubCategoryID { get; set; }
        public short TicketPriorityID { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

so I want to pass
MerchantID,TicketCategoryID,GroupID,TicketSubCategoryID,TicketPriorityID, Summary as property of object of CreateParameter and these three("Hash", "AccessKey","Path" ) as seperate parameters
as shown in signature of function createnew. but could not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER**
Try this in the controller:

```
public CreateTicketResult createnew(string MerchantID, string TicketCategoryID, string GroupID, string TicketSubCategoryID, string TicketPriorityID, string Summary,string Hash, string AccessKey, string Path)
{
   CreateParameter ObjParameter = new CreateParameter();
        ObjParameter.MerchantID = MerchantID;
        ObjParameter.TicketCategoryID = TicketCategoryID;
        ObjParameter.GroupID = GroupID;
        ObjParameter.TicketSubCategoryID = TicketSubCategoryID;
        ObjParameter.TicketPriorityID = TicketPriorityID;
        ObjParameter.Summary = Summary;


//code..........
//code.......
}
```

Else, use make a json object and pass it in the request so you can decode in in the controller, but the above method is much easier. It's all up to your preference.

Comment: i tried the endodeURIcomponent but it is now working,

Comment: @Nishal -i tried the endodeURIcomponent but it is now working, also I have tried like  Hash: "s", AccessKey: "ss", Path: "sd" but not working

Comment: Great! Can you kindly answer your own question with the working code?

Comment: sorry!.I have not found any solution yet, can you please do the needful more in depth? as soon as I got solution I will definetely post answer on my question.

Comment: I have a suggestion here @skiskd, you are passing 9 (all of them string) parameters to the controller, whereas the controller only accepts 4. This HAS to cause some error.
Why don't you make the controller accept all 9 string parameters as it is, and then create the CreateParameter object somewhere inside the method?
Or else use json to pass objects. 
I will update my answer with my first suggestion.